# Confirm PIN Creation on different screen

Tags: usability, app

I'm working on a mobile app and we ask for the user to create PIN to access the platform. We want to ask for the PIN confirmation and I'm wondering if there is any best practice that says the PIN confirmation should be in a different page or could be on the same page we asked for the PIN previoysly.

I've seen other players doing on 2 different screens (1 for PIN creation, 1 for PIN confirmation). I'm wondering if it's a bad decision to solve this on just one screen.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're free to go with any of the approach, I've seen both kind of players.

1. Doing on same screen.
2. Doing on different screens.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Answers are most helpful when they come with some rationale. The existence of both versions does not constitute a good rationale (their frequency may be wildly different, or it may be biased by development effort, or ...). Why do you think both options are equally suited, or even better, in which situations is which alternative better suited than the other?

Comment: Thanks, I've seen even banking applications use both approches.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of having it on two separate screens is that the animation of going to the next screen makes it clear to the user that the previous screen went successfully and they now have a new "task" (confirmation instead of re-entry).

You can achieve the same thing on a single screen, but I'd suggest doing so by having the screen move down to the confirmation field automatically (scrolling the screen for the user).

Or have the fields close together with clear labeling. That works fine too. As long as you clearly show a warning when the fields aren't the same.